# Should we rewrite titles into questions?

Tags: discussion, faq, questions

There have been some questions that don't have questions for titles.   Should we be changing those to questions (if you have >1000 rep) via edits?  Should we comment to the poster: "Please rephrase your title as a question." if under 1000 rep?

Any thoughts?

Examples:

- [forward foreign exchange rates](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/2826/forward-foreign-exchange-rates)
- [Trading with a leveraged account](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/2833/trading-with-a-leveraged-account)
- [credit card with daily purchase notifications](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/2836/credit-card-with-daily-purchase-notifications)
- [Foreclosure debt still on the credit report](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/2744/foreclosure-debt-still-on-the-credit-report)
- [Long Term Cash-Equivalent ETFs for “cash” allocation](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/2806/long-term-cash-equivalent-etfs-for-cash-allocation)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Titles *should* ideally be questions.

But, more important is ensuring a question title contains adequate keywords *relevant* to the question to make the question a more likely search result in Google.

In your first case above, for instance, I might re-title it "Online data source or web site for forward foreign exchange rate quotes?"

**A good title with the right keywords can often mean the difference between only dozens of search visitors, or *tens of thousands*.**  Case in point, this question got 55,000+ pageviews:

[Ontario harmonized sales tax (HST) transition benefit rebate cheques / OSTTB: Who, when, how much?](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/1224/ontario-harmonized-sales-tax-hst-transition-benefit-rebate-cheques-osttb-who)

The title above recognizes that individuals search on a variety of things:

- "hst rebate cheque"
- "osttb cheque"
- "harmonized sales tax cheque"
- "ontario hst cheque"
- "hst cheque how much"

So prefer verbose titles rich in keywords to short, terse titles.  The question words are sometimes good search terms so they can help too.  You'd be surprised (or not) how many people just type an English question into the Google search box!

(Addendum: Of course, sometimes a title can be **too** long.  Be reasonable :-)

Comment: Notably it recognized that people would be searching "cheque" not "check".  Excellent page view btw.

Comment: @C. Ross: Ah yes; the regional difference in wording.  Hadn't thought of that - it's just how I always spell "cheque" ;-) - but yes that's a good point too.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know if we should, but I have always done it on the sites where I have enough rep to do that kind of moderation.

Answer (score 1):

I agree totally with Chris's Answer and I can only add the similar debate on MSO.

- [How can we get more people to make their title a question?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/21606/how-can-we-get-more-people-to-make-their-title-a-question)
- [Why are the titles of all questions on the Trilogy Sites not in the question format?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/50438/why-are-the-titles-of-all-questions-on-the-trilogy-sites-not-in-the-question-form)

Comment: I particularly like this answer: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/21606/how-can-we-get-more-people-to-make-their-title-a-question/21608#21608

It gets at what I was asking which is should we edit them into questions and the opinion seems to be yes.

Comment: And this answer too: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/50438/why-are-the-titles-of-all-questions-on-the-trilogy-sites-not-in-the-question-form/50439#50439